# Form only posting first dynamically generated inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which have three different input elements. Each element child element is created by jquery dynamically.
My problem is, when I try to submit my form (in php) it post only first dynamic input value second and third dynamic input values are not posting.

```
<input type="text" name="first[]"><input type="button" id="first" value="first>
<div class="warp1></div>
<input type="text" name="second[]"><input type="button" id="second" value="second>
<div class="warp2></div>
<input type="text" name="third[]"><input type="button" id="third" value="third>
<div class="warp3></div>
```

**jquery code:**

```
var wrap1  = $(".wrap1");
var btn1   = $("#first"); 
 $(btn1).click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
 var appendText='<input type="text" name="first[]" />';
        $(wrap1).append(appendText); 

});

similar for other button
```

**php code**

```
print_r $_POST['first'];
print_r $_POST['second'];
print_r $_POST['third'];
```

If I add two-two dynamic element in every field then the result may like this `array([0]=>,[1]=>,[2]=>)` but this show for first element second and third element result is `array([0]=>)`

Comment: You misspelled the variable here: `$(warp1).append(appendText);`

Comment: First of all, there is a typo: ` $(warp1).append(appendText); ` should be ` $(wrap1).append(appendText); `

Comment: It is typing mistake in a posting of question otherwise it works.  Please tell me how can i post data of dynamic content

Answer (score 0):

You have  a few problems in the code you posted.
Think about the following code you wrote :

```
var btn1   = $("#first"); 
 $(btn1).click(function(e){ 
 //......

});
```

You took `$("#first")` in `btn1`. So next it should be `btn1.click(function(e){` instead of `$(btn1).click(function(e){` . Same thing applies for `$(".warp1")`;

Some problems in HTML were also there. The `value` attributes were not properly enclosed with commas.

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            var warp1  = $(".warp1");
            var btn1   = $("#first");
            btn1.click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var appendText='<input type="text" name="first[]" />';
                warp1.append(appendText);

            });



            var warp2  = $(".warp2");
            var btn2   = $("#second");
            btn2.click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var appendText='<input type="text" name="second[]" />';
                warp2.append(appendText);

            });

            var warp3  = $(".warp3");
            var btn3   = $("#third");
            btn3.click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var appendText='<input type="text" name="third[]" />';
                warp3.append(appendText);

        });

        });
```

**HTML and PHP together in same page:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


print_r ($_POST['first']);

echo "<br/>";
print_r ($_POST['second']);

echo "<br/>";
print_r ($_POST['third']);

}

?>
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" name="first[]"><input type="button" id="first" value="first" />
<div class="warp1"></div>
<input type="text" name="second[]"><input type="button" id="second" value="second" />
<div class="warp2"></div>
<input type="text" name="third[]"><input type="button" id="third" value="third" />
<div class="warp3"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I added the `form` which you did not include in OP. The form with empty value for `action` attribute submits to the same page. You can however use a value i.e. `action="somepage.php"` to submit to a different page.